# Triggering automatic replacements of certain strings

Tags: vimrc, unicode

I am using the Vim version 8.0 editor, mostly via GVim. I would like to be able to type unicode/greek characters like lambda, mu, alpha inside my Haskell scripts.

There is a vim plugin called [latex-unicoder](https://github.com/joom/latex-unicoder.vim) which is *almost* what I want. The disadvantage of the plugin is that I need to repeatedly go into Normal mode, press Ctrl-L insert the latex symbol for the character and then manually go back into insert mode.

This is quite tedious. Emacs has something called M-x set-input-method [RET] tex which automatically and immediately replaces the occurences of \lambda, \alpha by their corresponding Greek characters.

Since I intend to use only a handful of greek characters, I am willing to manually create such a dictionary of Greek characters for automatic insertion when their latex name is written.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: I've never used latex-unicoder so this might not work but if the `ctrl-l` mapping of this plugin is what you want excepted that it makes you quit insert mode, maybe you can try an insert mode mapping? Something like this `imap <C-l> <Esc><C-l>` or something more complexe which will make you go back to insert mode too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like
`:iab \mu µ`

Note however that this requires `:set isk+=\` which may not always be desirable.

Another approach is `:imap \mu µ` . But this has the drawback that things starting with \ will not show up until entered completely

Comment: Use `showcmd` option to see a mapping as you type it in, at the right end of the last line. Read [`:help 'showcmd'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27showcmd%27) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you can use [digraphs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13829/what-does-ctrl-k-do-in-insertion-mode#13831) to enter Greek characters and many others in insert mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> followed by a two character code (see `:h digraphs`).

For example, lambda, mu and alpha would be `l*`, `m*` and `a*`.

If you'd like to use snippets, [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) allows you to [define your own](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/ed3c5426a20bf1c06d7980946ada34fd9f93320e/doc/SnipMate.txt#L228) snippets. Another popular plugin is [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), which also describes how to [add your own](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/8803960a4e09daf1ad4d82e16a25bbdb4c78530e/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L510) snippets.

Comment: I use a [script](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/bk/digraphs.vim) to [define a "French" mode](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/digraphs.vim) where certain digraphs don't require the `<C-k>`. This could easily be done for greek letters, too. Alternately, enabling/disabling a set of abbreviations for the longer sequences like `\mu`…