# What does CTRL-K do in insertion mode?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, unicode

When I press ^K in my vim while I'm in insertion mode a '?' appears and then if I press a and then another character some strange characters appear the following are a few of the characters I could get that way:

> さたåだả۹۸あァǡ۸åさя

So What is happening here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It allows you to enter a digraph — it's a method of entering a more extensive range of Unicode characters using pairs of keystrokes. (See `:h digraphs`)

For future reference, you can find out what insert mode keystrokes do with commands such as: `:h i_CTRL-K`.